# How do i make the label change text on its own and delay too - swift?

Tags: swift, xcode

I need the label to change every 5 seconds on its own like a **slideshow** I am working with swift 3

.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a Timer and make the changes you need inside the function that is called by the timer. 
var timer:Timer!
timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.countDown), userInfo: nil, repeats: true);

Answer (score 0):

```
var getLocationtimer:Timer = Timer()     
self.getLocationtimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target:self, selector:#selector(YOUR_VIEW_CONTROLLER.updateLevel), userInfo:nil, repeats:true)
func updateLevel(){
     //Update label your here
}
```

This timer can help you achieve what you are trying to.

Comment: Yes that you can do according to your logic in the updatelevel() method